# Why does topshelf wait for input after it has executed a command?

Tags: topshelf

I have the following script to install a topshelf service:

```
$exePath = "./My.exe"

$service = get-service | Where {$_.Name -eq "MyService"}
if($service -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "Service already installed, will do a reinstall"
    if($service.Status -eq "Running") {
        Write-Host "Stopping service"
        & $exePath stop
    }
    Write-Host "Uninstalling service"
    & $exePath uninstall
}
Write-Host "Installing service"
& $exePath install
Write-Host "Starting service"
& $exePath start
```

When I run this script I have to hit the enter key between each step. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this i"m having the same issue.

Comment: No not really, since we aren't automating it 100% this isn't an issue for us at the moment. But if you figure it out please post an answer to the question :)

Comment: In the end for me i was stupidly Console.ReadLine() at the end of the console app that was using topshelf thats why. ARRRRRRRRRRRR

Comment: @feanz, same here... :) Found it yesterday.

Comment: That's why we need a condition on that debug convinience `Console.ReadLine()` like this one: `if ((System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) && (Environment.UserInteractive))`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to:  Richard Forrest and Tomas Jansson:

> `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the console app

ZoolWay recommends:

> `if ((System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) && (Environment.UserInteractive))`
>   `Console.ReadLine()`

Sorry for using others' ideas in this answer, but i think that this needs to be seen with probability of 100%. I would give as many upvotes to the answer/comment as the number of R in Richard Forrest's:

> ARRRRRRRRRRRR